# Why can't I use Chat?

Tags: support, chat

I have more than 2000 reputation but it tells me that I'm not allowed to use Chat. What to do ?

It gives me , this:

> Welcome to The Stack Exchange Network chat! You'll need 20 reputation to talk here. This site is moderated by the community, so please be respectful of your fellow The Stack Exchange Network users. And while you're at it, check out the FAQ!

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific with what it 'tells you' ?

Comment: @DanielRust , See the thread , I added details.

Comment: You're probably not logged in to the stackexchange network. Click on log in at the top of the page.

Comment: Try entering chat by clicking on the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) link at the top of the page, and see if you can get onto chat.

Comment: I agree with @DanielRust: the website `chat.stackexchange.com` is a "separate entity" (by SE reckoning) from `math.stackexchange.com`. It is possible to be logged into MSE and not into chat (you may notice this also if you have associated accounts on other SE sites which you don't use as frequently).

Comment: Thank you all :) now every thing works in favor of you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

(Just to get the question off the unanswered list.)